# 403 ошибка ответа сервера, сайт открывается, в индексе ПС

Tags: redirect, multilanguage, http-status-code-403

Есть конкурент по запросам в Яндексе. Известный авиаперевозчик. Сайт у них мультиязычный, с автоопределением и ручным переключением языка. При заходе на site.ru, он открывается, начинает подгружатьcя, через секунду в body у него подгружается прелодер и в этот момент сайт перееадресовывает на site.ru/ru. В поиске Яндекса у него три варианта site.ru/ru site.ru site.ru/en
При проверке его ответа сервера главной страницы выдает
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

```
Server: AkamaiGHost
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Length: 4598
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Content-Type: text/html
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Wed, 05 Jan 2022 14:35:15 GMT
Date: Wed, 05 Jan 2022 14:35:15 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

При этом главная открывается.

1. Почему переадресация на ру начинается не сразу, а когда частично
   происходит загрузка?
2. Как могла быть реализована перееадресация, не могу даже код
   переадресации определить?

Хотя-бы примерно, намекните.

3. Почему имея код 403 сайт открывается?

Comment: 1. 2. Наверное потому что там не переадресация, а вызов [history.replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API)

Comment: @andreymal не смог разобраться сайт аэрофлота, как у них так сделано заходишь на главную, загружается, а потом на /ru переходит. А ответ сервера главной 403. И вообще зачем так сделано непонятно

Comment: А код 403 видимо потому, что аэрофлот почему-то решил забанить лично вас, у меня ошибки нет и код 200 как положено

Comment: @andreymal странно и у меня сейчас показывает 301 ответ